# Very simple Javascript partial page refresh calling a .php page not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I've combed the internet for a few hours and still cannot make this simple example work.  I hope somebody can assist me.  I'm trying to use Javascript to display the contents of a php file.  The display should be refreshed often as ultimately it will be used to display text matches from a MySql db that match the characters entered in a search bar (similar to Google's search bar).  I'll use setinterval for that but I am not there yet.  My issue is that I have minial javascript/AJAX experience and just cannot make it work.  I've dumbed it down to a bare bones request and still cannot make it work.  Please suggest what isn't working:

The index.html where the content should be viewable is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {
$("#dynamic").load("blasty.php");
});

</script>
<div id="dynamic"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And blasty.php contains:

```
<?php
echo "hello cruel world!";
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks okay to me, but use `$(document).ready` rather than `$()`.  I don't think that will fix it, but it is preferred.  Better yet just `$(function () {`

Comment: Are you sure that `blasty.php` exists in whatever directory this page is shown in?  Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I've tried the $(document).ready method and $(function)... without luck.  Yes, blasty.php is in the same directory.  What do you mean by errors in the console?  I don't see any errors on the screen or in the source code.  Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using to debug?  If firefox, do you have firebug?

Comment: Just downloaded Firebug and it made the problem clear.  Thanks for your help and more info about the problem is in another of my comments on this page (I can't close out the question because I'm a n00b here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your blasty.php file is on the same domain.

Also, to help debug javascript, right click in Chrome or Firefox and go Inspect Element. Then go to the Console window and it will display most errors.

I also recommend this youtube video about javascript. I it helped me bridge the gap on some javasrcipt gotchas. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljNi8nS5TtQ

Here is a link about debuggers: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

As @Explosion Pills said, FireFox's Firebug is another great option. I will use both to help debug javascript. Firebug is nice because under the Net tab it will display the acutal http requests as they happen in the background, with the params, response, header info, etc.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dynamic").load("blasty.php");
    });
    </script>
    <div id="dynamic"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `document` variable in the `$()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dynamic").load("blasty.php");
});

</script>
```

Visually that's the only issue I see.

Comment: I've added the missing text that you pointed out but it is still not working.  I just see a blank page when I view index.html.  I'm using the new version of Firefox if it makes any difference.

Comment: Check the response in Firebug to make sure the request is going through and that blasty.php is in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I use `$.get` instead of `$.load`.

Try something like this:

```
$.get("blasty.php",
      { nbRandom: Math.random() },
      function(data){
        $("#dynamic").html(data);
      });
```

`nbRandom` is to prevent caching in IE.

Use Firebug to make sure there is a response from the AJAX and go from there.

Comment: They are roughly equivalent though. But I do think he should check the responses in Firebug or the Chrome Developers tool.

Comment: I got it, thanks for the help everyone!  After the prompt to check the Firebug console, I did the following:

1. Searched Firebug to see what it was.
2. It's a Firefox add-on for web developers.  Downloaded and installed it.
3. Refreshed the page with the console on, saw that it could not find the link to JQuery that I had in the header.
4. Updated the link to point to 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js' and now it works.

Thanks for the quick help everybody!